# How can I use Font Awesome (or other font icons) instead of the jQuery sprites in Primefaces DataTable?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf-2, primefaces, font-awesome

I'm using PrimeFaces to generate a datatable. The default sorting icons are chevrons from the JQuery library but as they are not Vector they look ugly. I wan't to replace them using some font like font awesome but I have no clue how to do this. 
The below CSS handles I can use to change the image to different sprites etc.

If I could somehow change the class primefaces adds from **ui-icon-triangle-1-n** to **af fa-sort-alpha-desc** for example I would already be helped.

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon{
        background-image: url("../Assets/images/jquery-ui/ui-    icons_0072b6_256x240.png");
    }
    .ui-datatable .ui-icon-carat-2-n-s {
    background-position: -160px 0 !important;
}

.ui-datatable .ui-icon-triangle-1-n{
    background-position: 0 -48px !important;
}

.ui-datatable .ui-icon-triangle-1-s{
    background-position: -64px -48px !important;
}
```

Comment: you can easily manipulate classes with jQuery. If that is not sufficient, you have to patch the PrimeFaces source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up with this bit of CSS for the `DataTable`:

```
.ui-datatable .ui-sortable-column-icon.ui-icon {
    background-image: none; text-indent: 0; margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
}
.ui-paginator > span:before, .ui-sortable-column-icon:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome; color: #fff;
}
.ui-paginator > span > span, .ui-paginator a span { display: none; }
.ui-paginator-first:before { content: '\f049'; }
.ui-paginator-prev:before { content: '\f048'; }
.ui-paginator-next:before { content: '\f051'; }
.ui-paginator-last:before { content: '\f050'; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s:before { content: '\f0dc'; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s.ui-icon-triangle-1-n:before { content: '\f0de'; }
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s.ui-icon-triangle-1-s:before { content: '\f0dd'; }
.ui-paginator .ui-state-disabled { opacity: .25; }
```

All the unicodes can be found here: http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Font Awesome offers some alternative icons:

-  fa-sort-alpha-asc `\f15d`
-  fa-sort-alpha-desc `\f15e`
-  fa-sort-amount-asc `\f160`
-  fa-sort-amount-desc `\f161`
-  fa-sort-numeric-asc `\f162`
-  fa-sort-numeric-desc `\f163`

### Update

After doing some CSS overriding for my theme and taking Kukeltje's comment into consideration I decided I would be a good idea to add a JSF `ResourceHandler` to the [theme I'm working on](https://github.com/jepsar/Jepsar-PrimeFaces-Theme).

Simply add the dependency to your project and add the resource handler

```
<application>
    <resource-handler>org.jepsar.primefaces.theme.jepsar.FontAwesomeResourceHandler</resource-handler>
</application>
```

The handler will detect PrimeFaces themes and will patch the CSS. It removes the jQuery UI icons and adds [Font Awesome rules](https://github.com/jepsar/Jepsar-PrimeFaces-Theme/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-jepsar/fontawesome.scss) (which includes a separate [icon mapping SCSS](https://github.com/jepsar/Jepsar-PrimeFaces-Theme/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces-jepsar/iconmapping.scss)).

Comment: Cool, thanks for posting. Maybe I'll ping the PF guys to write a blog about this. Or have them create a custom css that is included when you turn on a configuration in the web.xml and use this for **all** PF components

Comment: Cool... now the next step would be to also be ably to also change the [checkbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/booleanCheckbox.xhtml) image based icons to font-awesome text based icons, the [radiobutton](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml), for printing without images (and also theme consistency). And btw _"
    They look outdated
    The CSS is overly complicated
    The icons are bitmaps"_ the last one is true. The first and second only for the free themes, not [these], there they use 'less' (do you?). Maybe we should create one...

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the default / free themes (will update the readme). Radio buttons, check boxes, pick lists and calendar are already taken care of (see bottom of CSS patch). I'm also working on a free theme.

Comment: I'll add the theme CSS (what I've got so far) tomorrow

Comment: I've checked out the PrimeFaces showcase, tested the patch and did some tweaks in the CSS

Answer (score 1):

here is an example:

```
.ui-paginator-first.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all:before{
    content: "\f049";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: white;
}
```

you can find the codes you cann add for content instead of `"\f049"` in the font-awesome website http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/pencil/

the :before is important behind the css class