# Replace p:dialog close icon with FontAwsome icon using CSS

Tags: css, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 7.

I want to use p:dialog, when i use it the close of the dialog is an image (which is a default one).
I want to change it a FontAwsome icon instead of the default image.
How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Please provide us with a [MCVE] so that we might be able to assist you any further. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you use a modern theme you'll get PrimeIcons (vector) out of the box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change icon from jQuery UI to FontAwesome in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528966/change-icon-from-jquery-ui-to-fontawesome-in-primefaces)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856102/how-can-i-use-font-awesome-or-other-font-icons-instead-of-the-jquery-sprites-i